# Error loading PartitionExpressionProxy while starting up hive standalone metastore 3.0.0

Tags: java, kubernetes, hadoop, hive

I am trying to run HMS (standalone v3.0.0) in kubernetes while connecting to postgresql (with ssl enabled). I am successful in using `schematool -dbType postgres -initSchema` to build the tables required in postgres. however, `./start-metastore` returns with the following error:

```
MetaException(message:Error loading PartitionExpressionProxy: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.DefaultPartitionExpressionProxy
         class not found)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8536)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8806)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8723)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:222)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error loading PartitionExpressionProxy: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.DefaultPartitionExpressionProxy
         class not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createExpressionProxy(ObjectStore.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:683)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:677)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:754)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:525)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
        ... 11 more
Exception in thread "main" MetaException(message:Error loading PartitionExpressionProxy: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.DefaultPartitionExpressionProxy
         class not found)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8536)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8806)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8723)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:222)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error loading PartitionExpressionProxy: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.DefaultPartitionExpressionProxy
         class not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createExpressionProxy(ObjectStore.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initializeHelper(ObjectStore.java:491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:417)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:59)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStoreForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:705)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:683)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:677)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:754)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:525)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
        ... 11 more
2023-03-02 11:38:42,300 pool-2-thread-1 INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
```

What am i doing wrong?

How i've set it up:

**HMS dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY hadoop-3.1.0.tar.gz /opt/hadoop-3.1.0.tar.gz
COPY hive-standalone-metastore-3.0.0-bin.tar.gz /opt/hive-standalone-metastore-3.0.0-bin.tar.gz

RUN wget -O /etc/apk/keys/amazoncorretto.rsa.pub  https://apk.corretto.aws/amazoncorretto.rsa.pub  && \
    echo "https://apk.corretto.aws/" >> /etc/apk/repositories  && \
    apk update && apk upgrade && \
    apk add --no-cache curl bash && \
    apk add amazon-corretto-8 && \
    apk add amazon-corretto-8-jre && \
    tar -xvf /opt/hive-standalone-metastore-3.0.0-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/ && \
    tar -xvf /opt/hadoop-3.1.0.tar.gz -C /opt/  && \
    rm /opt/*.tar.gz

COPY postgresql-42.5.4.jar /opt/apache-hive-metastore-3.0.0-bin/lib

ENV HIVE_HOME=/opt/apache-hive-metastore-3.0.0-bin \
    CLASSPATH=/opt/apache-hive-metastore-3.0.0-bin/lib/ \
    HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.1.0 \
    JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-amazon-corretto \
```

**metastore-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
        <!--    Configure MetaStore as a server. To start more servers, change port-->
        <property>
            <name>metastore.thrift.uris</name>
            <value>thrift://meta-store.default.svc.cluster.local:9083</value>
            <description>
                - Thrift URI for the remote metastore. Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.
                - IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host
            </description>
        </property>
        <!--    For running MetaStore in standalone mode. -->
        <property>
            <name>metastore.task.threads.always
            </name>
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.events.EventCleanerTask</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>metastore.expression.proxy</name>
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.DefaultPartitionExpressionProxy
            </value>
        </property>
        <!--Postgres' connection details -->
        <property>
            <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
            <value>jdbc:postgresql://postgres-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:5432/hive?ssl=true&amp;sslMode=verify-ca&amp;sslcert=/etc/tls.crt&amp;sslkey=/etc/postgresql.pk8&amp;sslrootcert=/etc/root.crt&amp;sslpassword=postgres</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
            <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
            <value>postgres</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
            <value>postgres</value>
        </property>
        
        
        <!--URL of the default location for -->
        <!--    <property>-->
        <!--        <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>-->
        <!--        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse</value>-->
        <!--        <description>-->
        <!--            URI of the default location for tables in the default catalog and database.-->
        <!--        </description>-->
        <!--    </property>-->
        
        <property>
            <name>datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll</name>
            <value>false</value>
            <description>
                - Auto creates the necessary schema in the RDBMS at startup if one does not exist.
                - Set this to false after creating it once.
                - To enable auto create also set hive.metastore.schema.verification=false.
                - Auto creation is not recommended in production; run schematool instead.
            </description>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>datanucleus.autoStartMechanism</name>
            <value>SchemaTable</value>
        </property>
        <property>
            <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    
    </configuration>
```

If it helps, **kubernetes deployment yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hive-meta-store
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hive-metastore-deployment
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hive-metastore-deployment
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
      containers:
        - name: metastore
          image: hive-metastore-v0.0.1
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9083
              name: thrift-port
#          envFrom:
#            - configMapRef:
#                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - name: metastore-xml
              mountPath: /opt/apache-hive-metastore-3.0.0-bin/conf/metastore-site.xml
              subPath: metastore-site.xml
            - name: postgres-ssl-crt
              mountPath: /etc/tls.crt
              subPath: tls.crt
            - name: postgres-ssl-key
              mountPath: /etc/tls.key
              subPath: tls.key
            - name: postgres-ssl-root
              mountPath: /etc/root.crt
              subPath: root.crt
            - name: postgres-ssl-pk8
              mountPath: /etc/postgresql.pk8
              subPath: postgresql.pk8
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - "watch ps"
      volumes:
        - name: metastore-xml
          configMap:
            name: metastore-site.xml
        - name: postgres-ssl-crt
          secret:
            secretName: postgres-ssl-secret
            items:
              - key: tls.crt
                path: tls.crt
                mode: 0444
        - name: postgres-ssl-key
          secret:
            secretName: postgres-ssl-secret
            items:
              - key: tls.key
                path: tls.key
                mode: 0444
        - name: postgres-ssl-root
          secret:
            secretName: postgres-ssl-secret
            items:
              - key: root.crt
                path: root.crt
                mode: 0444
        - name: postgres-ssl-pk8
          secret:
            secretName: postgres-ssl-secret
            items:
              - key: postgresql.pk8
                path: postgresql.pk8
                mode: 0444
```

So when I `exec` into the pod and run `./schematool -dbType postgres -initSchema`, no issues, i can see that postgresql hive database i updated all the required tables.

The problem comes in when i `start-metastore`, and it'll come out with the error:  `Error loading PartitionExpressionProxy: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.DefaultPartitionExpressionProxy class not found`

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, any chance you solved it by now?

Comment: Yea, it seems like the xml in the configmap wasnt properly aligned. so once I aligned the xml properly in the configmap, it worked fine. because yaml is tab based - gotta make sure the configmap data.xml stuffs are also aligned properly. hope that makes sense